# Can a rel=canonical meta tag point to a 301 redirect URL?

Tags: redirect, web-crawler, google-search, canonical-link, canonicalization

I'm working on a project which has versioned URLs. I want the rel=canonical meta tag to always point to the latest version, and this can always be reached via a 301 redirect.

Here are the URLs:

- /example `301 redirect to /example/3`
- /example/1 `<link rel="canonical" href="/example" />`
- /example/2 `<link rel="canonical" href="/example" />`
- /example/3 `<link rel="canonical" href="/example" />`

Will this setup work? Which URL will a service like Google choose to index, or will it get caught in a "redirect loop" going between /example and /example/3?

Answer (score 1):

So this website is now being indexed by Google. Here's how Google reacts to this scenario:

- Results are shown for both `/example` and `/example/{latestVersion}` where `{latestVersion}` is the result of the 301 redirect (most recent version)
- The `/example` link appears first in the results
- Often the links to `/example/{latestVersion}` are only revealed if the user clicks on the following text:

  > In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 13 already displayed.
  >   If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included.

I am changing the code so that the canonical URL is always `/example/{latestVersion}`, to ensure duplicate content is not indexed.