# How to tell an HTTP client where to find the latest version of a file?

Tags: rest, http-headers, version, permalinks, semantics

I am designing an HTTP API  for a dataset. I want permanent links to each historical version of a file in the dataset as well as a URL that redirects to the latest version. I want to add a header to enable clients to discover the latest URL given the URL for a specific version:

```
GET /example/v1

200 OK
Link: </example/latest>; rel="latest"

GET /example/v2

200 OK
Link: </example/latest>; rel="latest"

GET /example/latest

303 See Other
Location: /example/v2
```

**I want to know**: is there a better value for the rel parameter than "latest" that I could/should use? Note: I am aware that I should add `Link: </example/latest>; rel="canonical"`, but `rel="canonical"` captures a different semantic than I want to describe.

| rel="latest" | rel="canonical" |
| --- | --- |
| This is where you can find the latest version | Hint: if you are a search engine, this is the page I want you to use when grouping a set of similar results |

It is not infeasible that I may want to serve `Link: </example/v2>; rel="canonical"` or even `Link: </example/v1>; rel="canonical"`

Similar questions:

- [Can a rel=canonical meta tag point to a 301 redirect URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32421892/14516046): How will *Google* handle *a given scenario*?
- My question: How to best *communicate* the *semantics* I want?

At the time of writing there is no suitable entry in [this list on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a better value for the rel parameter than "latest" that I could/should use?

A good place to look is the [IANA Link Relations registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml); there, you will find registered link relations, non-authoritative summaries, and a link to the authoritative reference.

Example

```
latest-version

Points to a resource containing the latest (e.g., current) version of the context.

https://www.iana.org/go/rfc5829
```

RFC 5829 is [Link Relation Types for Simple Version Navigation between Web Resources](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5829.html), and it of course includes a definition for [latest-version](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5829.html#section-3.2).

Comment: Thanks. I have looked on MDN, but it did not occur to me that there, off course, exists a registry.